# update table with a join on a temporary table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have two tables,

**tblFXRates**

```
  Base    Quote   Rate
  USD     JPY     1.5     
  USD     GBP     2.5 
  USD     EUR     1.75 
  EUR     JPY     1.5 
  USD     USD     1
```

**tblHoldings**

```
 FX      FXRate  
 EUR     null
 EUR     null
 USD     null
 GBP     null
 JPY     null
```

What I would like to do is update the FXRate in tblHoldings. So I want to select all the rates in the tblFXRates where the base is equal to USD. Then join the result of this query to the column FX in tblHoldings to update the FXRate. It should look something like below,

**Result**

```
 FX      FXRate  
 EUR     1.75
 EUR     1.75
 USD     1
 GBP     2.5
 JPY     1.5
```

I'm not sure how to do this as the nested query is throwing me. My attempt so far (is pretty rubish) is below,

```
update h
set h.FXRate = fx.rate
from tblHoldings h
inner join fx
on h.FX = fx.Quote
with fx as
( 
   select quote, rate 
   from tblFxRates 
   where base = 'USD'
)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `UPDATE FROM JOIN`:

```
UPDATE th
SET FXRate = tr.Rate
FROM #tblHoldings th
JOIN #tblFXRates tr
  ON th.FX = tr.Quote
WHERE tr.Base = 'USD';
```

<kbd>**[`LiveDemo`](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/383753)**</kbd>

Output:

```
╔═════╦════════╗
║ FX  ║ FXRate ║
╠═════╬════════╣
║ EUR ║ 1.75   ║
║ EUR ║ 1.75   ║
║ GBP ║ 2.5    ║
║ JPY ║ 1.5    ║
║ USD ║ 1      ║
╚═════╩════════╝
```

Alternatively you could use `MERGE` statement:

```
MERGE #tblHoldings AS th
USING #tblFXRates tr
  ON th.FX = tr.Quote
WHEN MATCHED AND tr.Base = 'USD' THEN
   UPDATE SET FXRate = tr.Rate;
```

<kbd>**[`LiveDemo2`](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/383757)**</kbd>

Which will detect corrupt data like duplicates:

```
INSERT INTO #tblFXRates(Base,Quote,Rate) VALUES ('USD','USD',1);
INSERT INTO #tblFXRates(Base,Quote,Rate) VALUES ('USD','USD',2);
```

Using `UPDATE` it passes silently.

Comment: ah yes there really was no need for the nested with! The merge is something new to me so thanks for that

Answer (score 1):

Try this.

```
update h
set h.FXRate = fx.rate
from tblHoldings h
inner join tblfxrates f on h.FX = f.Quote
where h.base = 'USD'
```

Answer (score 1):

I think this is what you want:

```
update h
    set h.FXRate = fx.rate
    from tblHoldings h inner join
         fx
         on h.FX = fx.Quote and fx.base = 'USD';
```